# SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working on an application where I am fetching the weather information from OpenWeatherMaps API and then plotting it on graphs using FlotJS.

The data is coming from:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=39.77476949&lon=-100.1953125

Where the lat, lon are dynamically generated. You can go to the link to get an idea of what kind of JSON response is sent back.

I am trying to construct the arrays first in order to pass them into the data object while plotting the graph like so:

```
var temp = [];
var humidity = [];
var rain = [];

$.each(response.list, function(i, item){
    if(moment(item.dt, 'X').isSame(moment(), 'day')){
        temp.push([moment(item.dt, 'X').valueOf(), parseFloat(item.main.temp)]);
        humidity.push([moment(item.dt, 'X').valueOf(), parseFloat(item.main.humidity)]);
        rain.push([moment(item.dt, 'X').valueOf(), parseFloat(item.rain.3h)]);
    }
});
```

`temp` and `humidity` were working fine. I cannot add precipitation. The precipitation values are in the `rain` object in `3h` and when I try to push it into the array, I get a console error saying:

> SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

How to go around this problem?

Comment: The problem is here: `item.rain.3h`. change this to `item.rain["3h"]`

Answer (score 5):

`3h` isn't a valid symbol, it's a numeric literal followed by an "h"; parser go boom.

You need `item.rain['3h']` instead.

Comment: Wow. Why couldn't I think of that. Sometimes it is simplest of things that confuse me. Thanks. I will accept it as soon as it lets me.